# Is there a way to run commands available in the command palette using Visual Studio Code's API?

Tags: javascript, vscode-extensions

I'm building a Visual Studio Code extension that requires a command only available in the command palette (as far as I know). I want to be able to control this command in JavaScript using VS Code's API. I'm looking for something like this:

```
vscode.commandPalette.run (A function in command palette)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This precise scenario is documented here: https://code.visualstudio.com/api/extension-guides/command.

Here's an example pulled from that documentation:

> ```js
> import * as vscode from 'vscode';
>
> function commentLine() {
>   vscode.commands.executeCommand('editor.action.addCommentLine');
> }
> ```

That same documentation page also links to this page about what builtin commands exist and their command IDs: https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/commands

For your learning, if you are interested, I found that information as the first search result by googling "`vscode api run command`".